# What is the occasion to use Eager Fetch in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I find it is very tricky to choose between `eager fetch` and `lazy fetch`. As we all know that `eager fetch` can preserve the data after the session is complete, and `lazy fetch` is more like get the data on demand and expired after the transaction finished, it feels like `eager fetch` may spend more resource and sometimes retrieve unnecessary data.

For example, if there are 100 orders in the shopping cart and each order contains several "items"(so there is a two-level relation), and we setup these relations in `eager fetch`, even only we want to retrieve a specific shopping cart attribute:

```
// JPA will run many queries for the expire timestamp
// if set all relation in ShoppingCart to Eager fetch...
Date expire = ShoppingCart.find(id).getExpireTimestamp();
```

it still gonna pull all orders and all items (by extra queries), which is a huge waste.

However, on the other side, I find the `lazy fetch` may not be faster, because Lazy fetch requires a transaction just to run a `select * from .. fetch join..`

So my question is, what is the meric to choose between `Eager Fetch` and `Lazy fetch`, and between memory cost(from `eager fetch`) and database transaction cost(from `lazy fetch`), which is a winner?

Comment: I tend to default to Lazy. I also think that the fetch specification is not all that important as I retrieve the data mostly trough queries (named queries, criteria queries) and on these the fetch mode does not apply.

Comment: You of course would use eager fetch if you knew that you will need all the data involved in the query. But even if you wouldn't need all it can be faster to retrieve unnecessary data instead of running another query for each lazy fetch. As you correctly noticed you have to weigh different kinds of cost. I think it comes down to experience and/or benchmarking. No generally applicable rules there. I tend to vote close for opinion based or too broad but I'd like to see if there are some good answers :-)

Comment: Take a look at this presentation from JavaOne 2014: [Lazy Versus Eager Loading Strategies for JPA 2.1](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2014/connect/fileDownload/session/7DF45BAE486FF80FD1990E15F374FAF8/CON1883_Wegrzynowicz-javaone2014-jpa.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

EAGER fetching is a [code smell](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/). If you load entities through the EntityMangager, then a JOIN is used. If you load them through JPQL/Criteria API, then secondary selects are employed.

It's best to set all associations as LAZY and use JOIN FETCH instead. The fetching strategy is a query-time responsibility and it should never be delegated to entity mapping.

A global fetch plan is a bad idea, especially since it cannot fit all application query scenarios.

So, you can safely use LAZY with query-time JOIN FETCH loading.